# Bootstrap Navigation Bar Distorting when I scale down (medium resolution) - Why?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I've starting off with **bootstrap** recently. I just ran into a trouble when I messed *a little* with bootstrap.css file. Everything else is perfect, it's just the **navigation bar.**
 Working fine at larger resolution but once I scale it down, it has started distorting. Brand logo is left aside and navigation links break down onto new line (have a look at attached screenshot).

[screenshot: bootstrap navigation bar distortion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxVlH.png)

PLEASE HELP!

Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist\](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is distorting because navigation bar width is bigger than its container
Use @media query for this screen size and reduce left right padding of menus and font.